# codeigniter session get blank values

Tags: codeigniter-2

i am trying to set some values in session and want to retrieve that session array in other function.
i can see that values are set properly but when i go to retrieve it shows blank.
i am setting the session data in Contact_View_Get method and want to retrieve in Contact_View method 
my CI version is 2.2.3

```
      public function Contact_View_Get()
      {
        $data['list']=$this->Contact_Model->Get_Contact_View();
        $sess_array=$data['list'];
        $this->session->set_userdata('deliverdata', $sess_array); 
        $this->session->set_userdata('cntids', $_POST['Contact_Ids']); 
        print_r($this->session->userdata('cntids'));die();


}
public function Contact_View()
{
    print_r($this->session->userdata('cntids'));die();
    $menu_records = $this->session->userdata('deliverdata'); 
    print_r($menu_records);die();
    $data['list']=$this->session->userdata('deliverdata');

    if(isset($_SESSION['deliverdata']))
    {

       die("df");
        $this->load->view('admin/templete/meta');
        $this->load->view('admin/templete/css');
        $this->load->view('admin/templete/header');
        $this->load->view('admin/accounts/contact/ajax/view_contact',$data);
        $this->load->view('admin/templete/footer');
        $this->load->view('admin/templete/js');
    }
     die("opf");


}
```